# Graphical bug when changing room

Tags: game-maker, game-maker-studio-2

[Here](https://youtu.be/_fbbdj2v2DY) is a video showing the problem I'm encountering.

And here's my room change code:

```
if(room_exists(room_previous(room))) room_goto_previous();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour happens because the game is rendering any frame without "cleaning" the previous one first, *and* your level view doesn't cover the whole screen (there are some transparent/translucent parts).

To solve this problem, you can either set a background or tell the game to clear the [display buffer](https://manual.yoyogames.com/The_Asset_Editors/Room_Properties/Room_Properties.htm) before drawing:

[image]

Clearing the buffer will fill it with a tint, after which object rendering takes place.

Comment: i aldready activated this

Comment: i added a black backround, it works now

Comment: Is it enabled in both rooms?